# How to make Minitest-Reporters work with Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, railstutorial.org, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been following along the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/) and I'm trying to incorporate the Minitest Reporters gem to my project as per instructions on [section 3.7.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-minitest_reporters)

So, test/test_helper.rb:

```
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
    require 'rails/test_help'
    require "minitest/reporters"
    Minitest::Reporters.use!
```

And the Gemfile:

```
    group :test do
      gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
      gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
      gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
    end
```

I was able to run `bundle install --without production` normally. Everything else in the app (including tests) runs smoothly but I don't get the same look/feel as in the tutorial:

[image: Some awesome testing]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of searching around I found out that this got fixed on the latest release on the Master branch in Github repository ([rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails)).

Props to [Prathamesh Sonpatki](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/03/test-runner-in-rails-5.html#comment-2584787142)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used with newer rails inside test_helper.rb (not sure if I've tried it in rails5):

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!(Minitest::Reporters::ProgressReporter.new,ENV,Minitest.backtrace_filter)
```

Comment: Still not working. I got 4 green dots. One for each run and that was it. No progress bars...